# Django AJAX - suggestions

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, view

I have made a functional site with django, but I have two forms which reside in separate pages. Since all the activities of the webapp will be centered around these forms, I want to put them both on the main page, to save space and preseve the "desktop" look and feel.

What would be the correct way to do it with Django?

To call the pages with the forms with Ajax call (I m thinking jQuery), thus maintaining the views relatively simple, or to merge the main page view with the forms views, which would result in messy code with lots of database hits, maybe unneccesary?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with Dajax (http://www.dajaxproject.com/), an awesome Django plugin for quick, simple AJAX implementation.

The index page could call a Dajaxice function with a callback javascript method for each of the forms. The Dajaxice function (a python method) would generate the html and the callback javascript method would write it to the screen element associated with that section.

I have a similar case where I have sections of data that all called separately by dajax, to populate a single edit screen.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I saw it once, but I didn't really consider it. I'll try it now. Tell me, how does it play with jQuery, which I need for other things?

Comment: My pleasure. Django is so awesome, I have been loving working with it. Actually jQuery can be used in conjunction with Dajax very easily. <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.dajax.core.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  
 {% dajaxice_js_import %}

Comment: You call a python method with Dajaxice.<module>.<Method>(<callback>, {<data dictionary>}); this executes the <Method> and returns whatever you want to the javascript <callback> method. I suggest <Method> returns a simplejson.dumps({dictionary}) which can be parsed by the callback method. Something like: return simplejson.dumps('form_id': 1, 'field_name': 'first_name', 'orig_value', ''). For the callback: function callback(form){ $('#form' + form.form_id).show(); }. Sort of a stupid example, but it uses jQuery to manipulate the screen and django/dajax/python to get data.

Comment: aha, I see. You practically call the entire view via dajaxice, and then dump the data via json and pass it to the callback method. Thank you, you ve been most helpful!

Comment: Just wanted to report back that Dajax and Dajaxice look awesome, but to set them up is a real pain. Anyway, they do work very nicely and they DO play nice with jQuery. I have just one more question: in your "main" view, you already had a form that you just populated with dajax or did you call the form itself from dajax?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3852/discussion-between-user464526-and-furbeenator)